# Get all inbox messages from Gmail with Zend framework 1.12

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to fetch all Gmail inbox messages via ZF1.12

I am using below code

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap(array('host'     => 'imap.gmail.com',

                                    'user' => 'myGmailEmailAddress',
                                     'port'     => '993',
                                     'password' => 'myPassword',
                                     'ssl'      => 'tls',
                                     'auth'     => 'login'
                                      ));

    echo $mail->countMessages() . " messages found\n";
    foreach ($mail as $message) {
        echo "Mail from '{$message->from}': {$message->subject}\n";
    }
```

but getting error

cannot read - connection closed?

Can anybody help me to direct correct way to do this?
Thanks,

Comment: Your hosting provider might closed the specified port for the security concern so that might be the issue behind this.

Comment: I have also tried it on localhost (local machine) but it wont work.

Comment: Have you test your port in localhost?? Try this: http://www.checkmyports.net/

Comment: I have checked with adding ip address 127.0.0.1 but it is saying port closed for 993 as well as for 465 (smtp). But SMTP mail send functionality is correctly working on my localhost only imap fetch mail is not working.